# Save a part of html to local storage later load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I need to save contents of a html div (id=tabela) to localstorage, so that the contents of the table can be loaded in another session via localstorage.
How to get the div contents into a variable?

```
var = tabelaContent; //<-- I need contents of <div id=tabela> in this 
localStorage.setItem("tabelaContent",tabelaContent);

// then, upon pressing the "load" button

localStorage.getItem(tabelaContent);
```

FYI if there is another way of making the table's content persistent, let me know

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML`**, like this:

```
var = tabelaContent; 

tabelaContent = document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML
localStorage.setItem("tabelaContent",tabelaContent);
```

Comment: Perhaps i've saved it. But when i use "load" it won't restore the previous state of the table. What did i do wrong?

Comment: I am using "localStorage.getItem(tabelaContent)"

Comment: document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("tabelaContent"); results in "tabelaContent" in place of the table.

Comment: now it works, after deleting "" from $("#tabela").html(tabelaContent); but console still outputs "tabelaContent is undefined"

Comment: Okay, fixed it by adding var tabelaContent; before document.getElementById.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you are looking for.

```
<div id="tabela">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
</div>

<button id="del" onclick="destroy()">Destroy div Content</button>
<button id="res" onclick="retrieve()">Restore content  from local storage</button>

<script>

  var tabelaContent = document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML;

    // Store Content
    localStorage.setItem("tabelaContent", tabelaContent);

function destroy(){
    document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML = "";
}

    // Retrieve Content    
function retrieve(){
    document.getElementById("tabela").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("tabelaContent");
}


</script>
```

**Check this** [working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RavvwB)