# How can I select all elements which are into a wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

My dom looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>something</span>
    <span>something else</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <div><b>whatever</b</div>
    <span>another thing</span>
</div>
```

Now I want to get a sequence of `<span>`s from the beginning of vale of `div.wrapper` until a tag else than `<span>`. So here is the result:

```
<span>something</span>
<span>something else</span>
```

Is there any idea how can I do that?

---

Here is what I've tried:

```
$(".wrapper").find("span").html();
```

But it doesn't support that "sequence" part.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/ ?

Answer (score 4):

As someone mentioned in the comment, you can use the `nextUntil` with the combination of `addBack` to add the first matching node:

```js
$('.wrapper > span:first').nextUntil(':not(span)').addBack().each(function() {
  console.log( $( this ).html() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span>something</span>
    <span>something else</span>
    <span>and more</span>
    <span>and once again</span>
    <span>last one</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <div><b>whatever</b></div>
    <span>another thing</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).html()` returns an object https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMyYq.png. While I want a long text of the result (spans should be combined as text).

Comment: @stack if you look at the `each()` function you will see I'm just outputting html to console, you can decide yourself what to do with the nodes

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to narrow your selector, combined it with `each()`, e.g. like this:

Stack snippet

```js
$(".wrapper span:first-child, .wrapper span + span").each(function() {  
  // get inner HTML
  //console.log( $( this ).html() );
  
  // get outer HTML
  console.log( $( this )[0].outerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span>something</span>
    <span>something else</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <div><b>whatever</b></div>
    <span>another thing</span>
</div>
```

---

In case where there can be any combination of element types, you need to make sure their selected index match their markup index.

In the below sample that would mean that the 3rd `span` in the selection will have index 2 but in markup it is the 6th element with an index of 5.

Stack snippet

```js
$(".wrapper span:first-child, .wrapper span + span").each(function(selected_index) {
  // if not same index, return
  if (selected_index != $( this ).index()) return;

  // get outer HTML
  console.log( $( this )[0].outerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span>something</span>
    <span>something else</span>
    <a href="#">link</a>
    <div><b>whatever</b></div>
    <span>another thing</span>
    <span>something 2</span>
    <span>something else 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I thought as well, it fits the question's description as well - *sequence of `<span>`s from the beginning of vale of `div.wrapper` until a tag else than `<span>`* +1

Comment: This `$( this ).html()` is an object. How can I make it pure text? *(not just the text, I need to keep the html too, but as plain text)*

Comment: However, problem is if there are other consecutive `span`s later, it will match them as well.

Comment: @gurvinder372 It will only select the first sequence of `span`'s, no matter how many. If to only pick 2, `nth-child(-n+2)` can be used.

Comment: See your code is an object https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMyYq.png .. I want to get it as a long string

Comment: @gurvinder372 Will check that in a sec.

Comment: @stack Use `$( this )[0].outerHTML` ... updated my answer

Comment: Here is my code in reality: `localStorage.setItem('qandaInputsValue7', $("#ask_q_tags span:first-child, #ask_q_tags span + span").each(function() { return $( this )[0].outerHTML }));`

Comment: You know, I need to store something like `<span>something</span><span>something else</span>` into localStorage. So I guess I should use `JSON.stringify()` or `.get()` or I don't know `:-(`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Correct, and since one can't cover that using CSS, I added an update which checks for matched selected/markup index.

Comment: @LGSon yes, works now. Please add the explanation as to why it works as well.

Comment: @stack Here is how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123035/save-a-part-of-html-to-local-storage-later-load

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>something</span>
  <span>something else</span>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <div><b>whatever</b></div>
  <span>another thing</span>
</div>

// start
var spanning = true;
// loop
$('.wrapper').children().each(function() {

  // if still good and this is a span
  if (spanning && $(this).is('span')) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  // still good but 1st non-span encountered
  } else if (spanning && $(this).not('span')) {
    // "break"
    spanning = false;
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5uogfd5j/5/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var keepGoing = true;
$(".wrapper").children().filter(function() {
  if (!$(this).is("span")) {
    keepGoing = false;
  }
  return keepGoing;
}).each(function(i) {
  console.log("filtered element: " + i + ", content: " + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>something</span>
  <span>something else</span>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <div><b>whatever</b></div>
    <span>another thing</span>
</div>
```

Here I'm defining a switch (`keepGoing`) outside the `filter` callback function and I'm setting it to `false` once I encounter a non-`span` element.