# How to save a list of "divs" to sessionStorage and display them when the user reloads the page?

Tags: javascript, html, session-state

I have an HTML page as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I have a JS file that listens for clicks of the enter key, and if the user clicks enter if adds another div.

```
//the event handler function
function captureEnterPress(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter" || event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        createNewDiv();
    }
}

//creates the div
function createNewDiv() {
    var body = document.body;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var labelText = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");
    p.appendChild(labelText);
    div.appendChile(p);
    body.appendChild(div);
}

onload = () => {
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", captureEnterPress);
}
```

I am trying to have the number of divs saved, so when the user reloads the page it shows the same amount of divs like he had before.

**What I tried**

I tried saving an array of all the divs to sessionStorage as follows:

```
var myStorage = window.sessionStorage;
var elementsArray = [];

//the event handler function
function captureEnterPress(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter" || event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        createNewDiv();
    }
}

//creates the div
function createNewDiv() {
    var body = document.body;
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var labelText = document.createTextNode("Hello World!");
    p.appendChild(labelText);
    div.appendChile(p);
    body.appendChild(div);
    elementsArray[elementsArray.length] = div;
    myStorage.setItem("storedPage", JSON.stringify(elementsArray));
}

onload = () => {
    var storedPage = JSON.parse(myStorage.getItem("storedPage"));
    if(storedPage){
        event.preventDefault();
        for(var i = 0; i < storedPage.length; i++){
            document.body.appendChild(storedPage[i]);
            console.log(storedPage)
        }
         
    }
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", captureEnterPress);
}
```

I just logged it to the console to see what the values are, but they are empty. So I tried storing the div.innerHTML instead, but then if I try to append it to the document I get and error that it's a String and not a node.

---

I am out of ideas, and I am pretty new to the whole state storing concept in front-end development I would appreciate if somebody could tell me what is the right way to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: I would say don't save direct `div` node into storage. Store actual html.

Comment: @navnath pls elaborate...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123035/save-a-part-of-html-to-local-storage-later-load

Comment: @zecuria pls read the full question to see why that solution didn't work in my case.

Comment: @BeeFriedman The [comment in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123035/save-a-part-of-html-to-local-storage-later-load#comment61787596_37123105) clarify how to use it i.e. not directly calling append instead modifying `.innerHTML`

Comment: @zecuria, got it! Thanks! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but enough to illustrate

```
function createNewDiv() {
    // create html content
    const div = `<div><p>Hello World!</p></div>`;
    // concat with body
    document.body.innerHTML += div;
    // save in array
    elementsArray[elementsArray.length] = div;
    // save in storage
    myStorage.setItem("storedPage", JSON.stringify(elementsArray));
}

onload = () => {
    var storedPage = JSON.parse(myStorage.getItem("storedPage"));
    if(storedPage){
        event.preventDefault();
        // get stored content array and join by empty '' and add into body
         document.body.innerHTML = storedPage.join('');
    }
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", captureEnterPress);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see in this code is that `JSON.stringify` is not able to convert DOM elements. [Article on how to do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880822/how-to-json-stringify-a-dom-element)

However, the better way is to save the innerHTML of some container, and then restore it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="div-container">
      <div>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var myStorage = window.sessionStorage;
var elementsArray = [];

//the event handler function
function captureEnterPress(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter" || event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    createNewDiv();
  }
}

//creates the div
function createNewDiv() {

  var divContainer = document.getElementById("div-container");
  const div = "<div><p>Hello World!</p></div>";
  divContainer.innerHTML += div;
  
  console.log(divContainer.innerHTML);
  myStorage.setItem("storedPage", divContainer.innerHTML);
}

onload = () => {
    var storedPage = myStorage.getItem("storedPage");
    if(storedPage){
        event.preventDefault();
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("div-container");
        divContainer.innerHTML = storedPage;
    }
    
    document.documentElement.addEventListener("keyup", captureEnterPress);
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wLgh1ef8/1/

Edit:
You always can see the content of sessionStorage using DevTools

F12 -> Application tab -> Session Storage

[image]